# What are some ways to add quality to the supply-demand model?

Tags: microeconomics, product-differentiation, monopolistic-competition

Please excuse me, I hardly know anything about economics yet.

When the quality of a product changes, the demand curve moves.  But what if there are different versions of a product, of varying qualities, on the market at the same time?  Is there standard way to model this?

For example, there are a lot of different restaurants of different qualities.  The quality is a subjective measure, but suppose it weren't.  I could draw one supply curve and one demand curve per restaurant.  Is there anything more interesting I could do?  For example something that takes account of the fact that a high-quality restaurant and a low-quality restaurant are to some extent substitutes for each other.  Does micro theory give any prediction about what the supply of different restaurants of different qualities will be?

If there's a better question like this that I could have asked, or a good keyword to search on, please tell me.

Comment: I think you want to read about product differentiation, most likely about vertical product differentiation.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_differentiation

Comment: @denesp thats almost a whole answer.

Comment: @Jamzy I posted it as a comment because its main component is a link. Perhaps someone will elaborate.

Comment: Any elaboration is very welcome.